# jQuery Sortable expand div on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i have 2 containers (A & B) which contain jQuery sortable containers and are also sections that can be expanded and collapsed to view/hide their content. When i grab an item from container A and am dragging it, i want to expand container B if it is collapsed. I am currently unable to get this behavior to work. I am using `connectWith` to link the 2 divs together. Here is my jquery code:

```
$$(".draggableContainer", this._sectionId).sortable({
            handle: ".measuresSectionBtn",
            connectWith: ".draggableContainer",
            cancel: ""
        }).disableSelection();
```

html:

```
<div class="containerA">
    <div class="draggableContainer">
       //draggable items in here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="containerB">
    <div class="draggableContainer">
       //draggable items in here
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding a `mouseenter` jQuery event on `.containerA & .containerB` but during the dragging those events don't fire. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suspect we'd need more of an example. This is too vague.

Comment: Seems like Accordion and Sortable do not like working together. Working on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h1jc4car/2/

Comment: Updates that make it more responsive. Also, now my helper is being hidden along with the source Sortable when the Accordion panel is hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h1jc4car/5/